# Why are ignition lock cylinder so greased on the outside?

Tags: ignition, locks

A while ago I removed the ignition lock cylinder.  When doing so I noticed grease/lubricant around it and don’t know why but I wiped it off and put the cylinder back.

Why was there grease/lubricant in it and could moving this leaf to other problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the previous lock have corrosion issues?

Comment: @Solar Mike I dont know if there ever was a previously corroded lock cylinder as I never replaced the lock cylinder since I bought the car, but at 165k miles there may have been.  A while ago while replacing the ignition switch the lock cylinder accidentally came out and I noticed it was covered in grease, I wiped it off and put it back so am wondering if they are manufactured like that, if your meant to grease them and why incase I introduced any problems by removing the grease.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are packed with grease to reduce wear and provide many years of life - key cylinders, cable mechanisms, shifters, actuators, levers of all kinds, .  All that grease does not interfere with electrical conductivity.  If you remove it, you will reduce the life expectancy of the part.